# How can I edit the URL of a taskbar icon pinned by Edge?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts, microsoft-edge

I'd like to pin a website to my taskbar using Microsoft Edge, namely `https://example.com/calendar/today`.
However, I cannot use Edge's menu because upon browsing that URI the website immediately forwards to, say, `https://example.com/calendar/2022-04-15`.

Thus, my plan is to pin the latter URI to the taskbar (using Edge's menu) and then retrospectively editing its URI.

I have been unable to track down the location where websites pinned to the taskbar are stored. Is it even stored in the file system (or is it in the registry)? For example, not a single website that I have pinned to my taskbar appears in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`

Comment: You can try creating a shortcut with the command `cmd /c "start https://example.com/calendar/today"` and once you have the shortcut created, right-click it and pin that to your taskbar. Alternatively, you can move that shortcut to `shell:startup` so that it automatically starts when your computer starts.

Answer (score 0):

Create a "quick link" with a custom url on the new tab page, then hover over the quick link and select the "more options" menu. You should have a prompt to create a new task bar link